# Should the tag [mllp] be a synonym of [hl7-v3]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

The [mllp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mllp) tag has no wiki and only three questions.

From the page [HL7 Version 3 Standard: Transport Specifications - MLLP](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=55)

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The purpose of the MLLP Protocol (Minimum Lower Layer Protocol) is to provide both a minimalistic Open Systems Interconnection (OSI)-session layer framing protocol as well as a minimalistic reliable transport protocol. If security is an issue, additional protocols or technologies will have to be layered on top of MLLP to achieve these goals.
>
> ALTERNATIVE NAMES
>
> HL7 Version 3 Standard: Transport Specifications - MLLP may also go by the following names or acronyms:
>
> "V3 Minimal Lower Layer Protocol (MLLP), Release 2", "Reaffirmation of the HL7 Version 3 Standard: Transport Specification - MLLP, Release 2", Transport Spec MLLP, MLLP

Should the tag wiki be created or should it be a synonym of [hl7-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-v3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those should not be synonymized.

An MLLP will transport an HL7. The MLLP is just a protocol for transport of the information. "transport specifications are not to be confused with the content of transmission infrastructure" (from the same page you link).

The MLLP is the transport specification, and is similar to TCP/IP except that the "packets" if you will, the HL7 information, can be spread across multiple traditional packets. In order to determine where this information resides, its structure is the HL7 and uses specific markers for when the information both starts and stops.

While MLLP and HL7 may be used in the same context fairly often, I do not believe they are synonymous and as a result should be left separate.

The wikipedia page on HL7 states this about MLLP:

> A large portion of HL7 messaging is transported by Minimal Lower Layer Protocol (MLLP), also known as Lower Layer Protocol (LLP).[13] For transmitting via TCP/IP, header and trailer characters are added to the message to identify the beginning and ending of the message because TCP/IP is a continuous stream of bytes. Hybrid Lower Layer Protocol (HLLP) is a variation of MLLP that includes a checksum to help verify message integrity. Amongst other software vendors, MLLP is supported by Microsoft,[14] Oracle[15] and Cleo.[16] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure, hence I asked.  I've proposed a wiki entry for it.