# Can we blow away some of the Tumbleweeds?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, tumbleweed-badge

I've had some spare time on my hands recently, so I've been looking at the [Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) and wondering if there's anything we can do  about this growing list of mostly unanswered questions. The badge has been awarded well over half a million times now, which is a pretty significant portion of the questions asked in Stack Overflow's history. It's a lot of questions that just get ignored.

[Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) and [Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) were kind enough to send me a list of all of the questions that had been awarded the Tumbleweed badge (up to about a week and a half ago). The data includes QuestionId, Title, Awarded, UserId, DisplayName, Score, ViewCount, Tags, AnswerCount, LastEditDate, CreationDate, ClosedDate, DeletionDate, and FirstAnswerDate. I spent some time poking and prodding at the list, and wanted to share the results and see if we could come up with some ways to reduce the number of these questions that go unanswered.

- **Proportion of questions with no answers:** 73.8% (390677 / 529639)
- **Proportion of questions that did get at least one answer:** 28.2%
  (149479 / 529639)

If you're wondering why those numbers don't add up to 100%, it's because there are two ways of looking at whether a question is answered or not. Count the number of answers, or look at when the first answer was posted. I used both methods to check for consistency, and of course they weren't. The discrepancy is due to a little over 10,000 questions that did receive an answer that was later deleted. Either way you look at it, the answered rate for Tumbleweeds is well below the site average of 74%.

Of those that did get answered, **75.8%** (113292) received only one answer.

[image: Number of Answers (to answered Tumbleweeds)]

- **Proportion of closed questions:** 1.6% (8320 / 529639)

That's not a typo. Only 1.6% of these questions get closed. That was shocking until I considered that this is the set of questions we ignore. It makes sense that they don't get enough views to be closed by the community.

- **Proportion of deleted questions:** 47.9% (253540 / 529639)

That's not a typo, either. Far more of these questions get deleted than closed because there's a script that runs that deletes questions with zero score, no answers, and low views after one year. It makes sense that a lot of these questions would fit that criteria.

---

So far we've identified a problem and a partial solution. These questions aren't getting enough attention to be answered or closed by the community, so a script is deleting them after they sit around for a year. Can we do better than that? Let's take a closer look at the questions that do get at least one answer to see if we can identify what sets them apart.

First, I want to look at how long it's taking (in days) for Tumbleweeds to get an answer.

```
 > quantile(time_to_answer, c(.1, .5, .90, .95))
       10%        50%        90%        95% 
  7.442454  48.278021 281.156600 357.092005
```

At the low end of the scale we can see that only about 10% of these questions are getting answers by the time they get the Tumbleweed badge a week later. Half of them are getting answered in 48 days, and 95% of those that do get answered do so in just under a year. (This should not be surprising, since we already saw that most of the ones that don't get answered are automatically getting deleted after a year. This pretty much guarantees that the majority that *are* answered will be answered within one year. It's almost a definition.)

Next, I want to look at how many questions are getting edited, to see if that makes a difference in whether or not they get answered.

- **Proportion of all Tumbleweeds that get edited:** 35.8% (189825 / 529639)

That was a bit of a surprise, considering only 1.6% of them get closed. However, it does take five votes to close a question, and the author can edit it themselves.

- **Proportion of answered Tumbleweeds that were edited:** 42.4% (63399 / 149479)
- **Proportion of unanswered Tumbleweeds that were edited:** 33.3% (126426 / 380160)

9% isn't as big a difference as I would expect, but at least it's in the right direction. There does appear to be a positive correlation between a question getting edited and it getting answered. This makes me wonder what effect there is based on *when* a post is edited. I already have the edited posts split into those that were answered and those that weren't, so I can look at the differences between when the questions were posted and when they were last edited to see what difference time of edit makes.

```
> quantile(post_to_edit_ans, c(.25, .5, .75, .95))
        25%         50%         75%         95% 
  0.0252662   1.5239352  96.1937789 725.6703183 

> quantile(post_to_edit_unans, c(.25, .5, .75, .95))
         25%          50%          75%          95% 
  0.01089120   0.06153935   1.26274016 183.80472512
```

Here we see a huge difference. Posts that were answered (first group) were edited over a much longer span of time than those that weren't answered. 50% of the *answered* questions were last edited  1.5 days after being posted, while 50% of the *unanswered* questions were last edited just 0.06 days (88 minutes) after being posted.

Questions that are edited within minutes of being posted aren't likely to get more attention than posts that aren't edited at all. It's better to edit them later, presumably so they get bumped to the Active page at a different time of day, or on a different day altogether.

---

#### Tags

[Andy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy) suggested a few more things to look for in the comments, including a couple of questions about how Tumbleweed questions are tagged. I looked at how many tags are used, and of those questions with only one tag, whether or not one of the most popular 36 tags was used.  Here are those results.

[image: Number of Tumbleweed questions asked with 1-5 tags]

The proportion of answered questions doesn't deviate much from the overall Tumbleweed answer rate (28.2%) that we saw above, no matter how many tags are used. It's between 25 - 30% for each category. Number of tags used doesn't seem to make much difference.

I also found that among those questions with only one tag, 16% of the answered questions were tagged with one of the 36 most popular tags, while 21% of the unanswered questions were tagged with one of the 36 most popular tags (20% if you look at the combined set). Those numbers aren't very far apart, but they are very low. (9% of all questions on Stack Overflow are tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) alone.) This seems to confirm what many of us have long suspected, which is that questions that are *not* tagged with one of the more popular tags are more likely to be ignored.

---

#### Title and Body lengths

Andy also asked for a rough breakdown of the lengths of both answered and unanswered posts. I thought it might be a good idea to look at titles as well, since that's what people first see and use to decide whether to view a question or not.

```
> summary(title_lengths_ans)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  12.00   39.00   51.00   53.54   65.00  150.00 

> summary(title_lengths_unans)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.00   39.00   51.00   54.08   66.00  180.00
```

I have the titles for all 500k+ Tumbleweeds, so these summaries are for the entire data set. As you can see, these numbers are nearly identical. Title length apparently doesn't play a part in whether a Tumbleweed gets answered or not.

Body lengths were a little bit more difficult to obtain. I don't have the full body in my data set, so I took a random sample of 1000 QuestionIds to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. I only drew from the set of non-deleted Tumbleweeds, since SEDE doesn't seem to have deleted posts to return. If anyone wants to run their own tests, you can find those Ids in the query [Tumbleweed Random Sample (not deleted)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/322563/tumbleweed-random-sample-not-deleted). (Note that you currently only get 984 results. I guess a few of those randomly selected posts were deleted in the past couple of weeks.) Here are the body length summaries:

```
> summary(nchar(answered_sample$Body))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     51     459     810    1311    1525   15360 

> summary(nchar(unanswered_sample$Body))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   77.0   498.5   891.0  1608.0  1668.0 25770.0
```

Unanswered questions are definitely longer, but only by about 300 characters (50-60 words) on average. I guess the lesson to be learned here is that if you're going to try to edit a Tumbleweed into shape, help the author get to the point and make the post more concise. (Yes, I can see the length of this post, and I get the irony in that recommendation.)

---

#### User Reputation and Activity

Several people asked about the activity of users who received the Tumbleweed badge. I didn't have any information about users in my data set other than their IDs, so I had to go to the Data Explorer with a random sample to make some estimates. You can see the query [Random Sample of Tumbleweed Awardees](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/324312/random-sample-of-tumbleweed-awardees) if you want to dig deeper than I do below. The results are mixed.

First I just looked at the reputation of users who were awarded the badge.

```
> quantile(randUserQueryResults$Reputation, c(.25, .5, .75))
25% 50% 75% 
  1  18 113
```

We can ignore the mean because there are a handful of very high-reputation users that skew it high. The quantiles tell the real story. At least one-fourth of the users who have been awarded the Tumbleweed badge only have 1 reputation. (That's their reputation today, not when the badge was awarded.) Half of them have a reputation of 18 or less, and three-fourths have a reputation of 113 or less. This confirms any suspicions people might have had that most of the people who ask Tumbleweed questions are new or at least low-reputation users.

The next thing that I looked at was a little bit more encouraging. I wanted to get an idea about whether or not people who asked Tumbleweed questions were even returning to the site after posting the question. I looked at the date the Tumbleweed was awarded and compared it to the user's last activity on the site. Out of 1000 users, only 86 of them never returned to the site after the Tumbleweed badge was awarded.

Here's a summary of the number of days between when the badge was awarded and the user's last access:

```
> quantile(awarded_to_last_active, c(.25, .5, .75))
      25%       50%       75% 
 62.93141 293.73100 730.20633
```

This shows that only 25% of users who ask a Tumbleweed question are active on the site for about 60 days or less after the badge is awarded. This is good news, since it means that a good number of users would be back at least once to see a system message or comment asking them if they're still interested in an answer to their question if that message was left at the time the Tumbleweed was awarded. If they don't take some action within that time (edit the question or delete it themselves), it's probably safe to delete it if it still has low views and no answers or upvotes.

---

#### Suggestion for improved handling of Tumbleweeds

In addition to deleting questions with low views, no answers, and zero score after one year, I think it would help get some more questions answered if one of the following actions were taken:

1. Create a new review queue out of the Tumbleweed badge. Basically, just add a question to the queue as soon as the badge is awarded. Older Tumbleweeds could also slowly be introduced to the queue.
2. Add questions that are awarded the Tumbleweed badge to one of the existing review queues. I think [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) would be the most appropriate, but [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) might also work.

Either one of these actions would get more views for questions that have largely been ignored, and allow the community the chance to either vote to close these questions earlier, or edit them into shape so that they can be answered.

---

#### Further Analysis

If anyone can think of any other ways to identify what's different about Tumbleweed questions, I'm open to suggestions. I have ids for over half a million of them, so it would be far easier now to query the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) or [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) with a random subset of ids to get even more information.

I also already have several fields that I didn't use yet (tags, titles, score, view count, etc.) for the whole data set. If you can think of ways that these pieces of information might be used to identify how the questions can be improved, or how the system might use that information to suggest improvements to post authors or reviewers, let me know in a comment or an answer. I'd be happy to run more tests on this data.

Comment: An issue with focusing on the badge is that it's awarded once per user. This makes sense as far as badge-giving is concerned, but it eliminates from consideration a large pool of questions that were just as much overlooked, but were not the first question by that user to be overlooked.

Comment: I think you're suggestions make sense. I've seen questions that gave the OP's the Tumbleweed badge just because he/she didn't choose the proper tags. Nevertheless, with the ammount of plugins / frameworks / specific projects (like gulp/grunt tasks or angularjs directives) that have been created in the most recent past, I think it's normal that growth of the badge's attribution.

Comment: @Yes That's a good point. The system should probably queue any question that meets the criteria for Tumbleweed, regardless of whether the user has it already.

Comment: I don't have a suggestion, but I do have a few data points that would be interesting to know (and could lead to suggestions): 1. How many of these questions have a single tag? 2. How many of these single tags are not one of the top 30 tags? 3. How many are in the top 30 tags? 4. What is the reputation of the user? 5. What is a rough break down of the length of the post? #4 may not be feasible for all of the questions, but I'm more interested in how many are new vs established users (perhaps a couple rep blocks would be helpful). #5 would be helpful to see if longer vs shorter posts is a factor

Comment: Those are all good questions, @Andy. I definitely can't answer #4 and #5 for all Tumbleweed questions, but I should be able to take a random sample of question ids and come up with a good estimate from the API data.

Comment: Tumbleweed needs to be burned though, else it'll blow to your neighbour's plot

Comment: Once a mod, always a mod, eh?

Comment: Nice research! It would also be interesting to see the profile of users that get this Tumbleweed badge. I guess most of them are low-rep and may not come again; so the effort to get their question into a review queue to clean them and ask for improvements may be cut by the fact that no feedback may be providen by the asker.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You can't just quit cold turkey. ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard If you have so much spare time, maybe you should just become a mod again? :)

Comment: @fedorqui It's going to take a little bit of digging, but I'll see if I can come up with a way of estimating user activity around the time the Tumbleweed question was asked.

Comment: @bluefeet If my other plans fall through, I'll have to run in the next election. ;)

Comment: Went back and looked at mine only to re-realize that I had posted and accepted my own answer ... though I still have yet to figure out why I was downvoted ... maybe we could ask that those that have been awarded the badge take a look and see if they can provide their own answer now?

Comment: How many of these questions received close votes, but just not enough to reach closure?

Comment: Talking of tumbleweed's I just managed to get one for a meta question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295228/should-the-tag-mllp-be-a-synonym-of-hl7-v3

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I answered your tumbleweed, it took some reading though :)

Comment: We run into this problem on SQA.se, and so gets as many questions in ten minutes as we get in 6-8 weeks. I can only imagine it's going to be a lot more of an effort to clean this up on SO.

Comment: Is there a way to view all tumbleweed questions for a given tag?

Comment: @Nit No, there's no easy way to get at this data. I asked permission to scrape data from the [9000+ badge pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed), but someone on SE's staff offered to query the database for me and send me the results instead.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think the ability to do so would greatly increase accessibility of tumbleweeds. The results might not differ too much from regular unanswered question search, but it's hard to tell without trying.

Comment: Thanks for those updates. I agree with your suggestion about making the post more concise. I'm surprised that number of tags didn't have much of an influence.

Comment: @Andy You're welcome. I appreciate your feedback. I'll update again after I pull some user info from the API, maybe this weekend. I was surprised by the tags too. I would have bet real money that more tags were better, but that's why we look at the data instead of just relying on our assumptions. :)

Comment: What percentage of these questions are related to a major framework?  Take your pick for a sample, but Spring, Dropwizard, Rails, Laravel, Flask, Sinatra, and Angular to name a few may be a good place to start.  I wonder if we're ignoring the questions that are more complex which involve those frameworks.

Answer (score 55):

I glanced over page 500 of the "new questions" list to peek at some tumbleweeds-to-be. My observations:

- Surprisingly, most of them were pretty good questions. I was expecting mostly "my homework assignment doesn't compile" and the like, but in fact I would only have downvoted/closevoted two of the twenty or so I examined.
- They were mostly really specialized. Many of them related to interactions between two particular frameworks/systems. I suspect that, in the lifetime of StackOverflow, nobody has ever asked a basic question about Java syntax and been tumbleweeded.
- Some would clearly have required a long, interactive troubleshooting session with the asker to resolve. While these generally had plenty of information in the original question, it was unlikely that anybody could have gone directly from that to "this is what's wrong" with confidence.

I don't care about the last category getting more visibility; I think back-and-forth-troubleshooting-style questions suck away answerer resources while adding little long-term value to the site. The specialized questions, though, would be really nice to service more effectively.

I honestly can't see what adding yet another review queue would do. Just because I've got lots of digits in my reputation number, doesn't mean I'm any more able to answer your question about integrating a legacy ColdFusion codebase with Joomla. There's probably three people on the site who could help you answer, and none of them are looking at that queue.

What I think we should definitely do, is improve the front page question selection on a per-user basis. I'm not sure what the current algorithm for "interesting" is, but based on the questions I'm being shown, it's certainly not succeeding in showing me interesting questions. Every now and then I manually search for some subject tags that I know I am particularly knowledgeable in and that are not widely serviced on SO, and there's almost always something there waiting for me. I would suggest that even a naive data mining algorithm, were it to poke around in my history, would have absolutely no difficulty figuring out what those tags are. So why is the front page showing me a question about "angularjs"? I don't know what that *is*, and apparently 15.2k other people do, so it's not like it needed to shotgun some visibility. What's it doing on my page, pushing some tumbleweed-to-be onto page 2?

Comment: I've looked around on that list often, and I agree with your observations about what kinds of questions get the badge. Some do just need to be closed, but a lot of them seem like reasonable questions that just need the right person to see them. Putting them in a queue wouldn't be meant to *directly* get them viewed by the right person (i.e., a reviewer), but might get them edited, retagged, or otherwise bumped so that the right person will see them later.

Comment: Maybe those interactive trouble shooting questions should be rephrased from "What is wrong?" to "How do I debug this type of problem?". That is very useful, and could be answered with confidence.

Comment: @David Maybe. But since those questions aren't getting much visibility anyway, and since general debugging information is (IME) generally not what the asker is looking for or likely to appreciate or reward in any way, that's likely to be a thankless task.

Comment: The review queue could start splitting "this requires knowledge of two really specialized systems" from "this will require debugging help".  The first category can be highlighted, the second can be left to blow away?  Take one of your "two specialized areas of knowledge" -- couldn't looking at what tags someone follow help you find the person who could answer it?

Answer (score 22):

Anyone who's spent much time on Stack Overflow will be aware - rep awards are much higher for newer questions and being first to answer. That's because - as far as I can tell - most people look at the 'newest' queue. So there's more potential upvotes, and more potential answers.

Having dug up some older questions to answer, I can say - it's very rare to get any sort of positive result at all - often the original asker has gone away entirely, and no one else really looks. (Occasionally you'll pop up in the 'Late Answers' queue, but that seems mostly geared around stopping spammers).

I don't know what the solution is though really - I honestly think the people who contribute an answer to a long standing, but unanswered question should have a higher rep reward to it, than the upvotes scored for answering yet another 'why does my regex not work' question.

I can only suggest perhaps, that we need to think in terms of *some sort* of rep award scaling to incentivise looking through the backlog. Bounties sort of do this, but they expire (and also - who's going to bounty a random old question? There's plenty of those)

Comment: _"rep awards are much higher for newer questions and being first to answer"_: Not always.  Yes, these may get you a few quick upvotes on fgitw answer to "why does my regex not work", the trick is to find a **good** question to answer which will be useful to many in the future, and you will get positive results. For example, your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713167/perl-cant-modify-constant-item-in-substitution/26713267#26713267) is useful to many people, and it will continue getting upvotes beyond the initial few.

Comment: It would be nice to have some kind of reward for answering a question that once won a Tumbleweed. Somthing like [Revival](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) and [Necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

Comment: @JonasCz of all the answers I've given, that's ... one I'm almost ashamed of actually - it's a flippant answer to 'you typoed'. And yet it's also the one that's garnered a lot of upvotes, which I think means the problem is a 'low hanging fruit' one. It's obvious to anyone who's done much `perl` what the problem is there - more eyes, and trivial to know it's 'correct' which means more upvotes.

Comment: @Sobrique, Okay, I don't know perl, just picked your highest voted one.

Comment: That's fair enough, but also sort of makes my point :). By rights, that question probably should have just been closed with a `typo` close reason. I've written - what _I_ think are considerably higher 'value' answers, which because they're a bit more niche and on older questions ... don't get many views at all, and are also harder to verify as correct. (At least, that's why I _think_ they don't/didn't get upvoted much - I'd be interested to see if others concur).

Answer (score 13):

Bill did an amazing job in his analysis. We need to get him more free time, ideally in copious quantities.

What this boils down to is identifying questions that *nobody* cares about any longer. If, and *especially* if the author of the question hasn't been to it in a reasonable amount of time *and*

- The question remains unanswered
- The question has a score <= 1
- The view count <= 50

.. then it's probably time to cull. Problem is, we don't explicitly track who visits what, at least not meaningfully enough to readily tell the last time you happened upon something that you wrote. Adding that would introduce all *kinds* of creepypants complexity, so we've got two options:

- Go by the date of the last edit
- Show something to the authors of these questions that basically lets them say "I still care about this" when they view stuff that would be caught in this net.
- A combination of the two

Think of it as a newspaper in the break room at your office. I don't care if it's from 1976 as long as *someone* is still reading it; I'm happy to let it occupy some room on a table. The minute *everyone* stops caring about it, it becomes litter.

Unanswered *this* long, these questions have very little intrinsic value and can be asked again, so the metaphor really does apply.

We're seeing this sort of question gum up the helper queue to some extent, where folks post a question and then see what they really *meant* to ask in the related links, then we don't see them for another week. I think the trick here really does lie in figuring out when the world stopped caring about something, with varying levels of aggressiveness.

We're going to be doing a bunch of split tests and number crunching over the next 30 days, gotta run some more numbers, but we might be onto something.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll wrangle with the API a little bit to see if I can spot any trends in user activity around the time that Tumbleweeds are posted-awarded. The biggest surprise in this for me so far has been the huge number of these that are just deleted, but your "newspaper in the breakroom" analogy is spot on. I'd love to see more of these things get *answered*, but it's ok to let go of some of them too.

Answer (score 9):

As the recent winner of a Tumbleweed badge of my own, I have a suggestion.

I asked a question that was incredibly niche.  I got no answers, one commenter telling me I was doing the wrong thing (*grumble grumble*).  So I hacked around the problem/back-burnered it indefinitely.  The question stayed open because I A: held out hope that someone would come and tell me how to do things properly, and B: just kind of forgot I asked it.

On seeing this post, I went back and deleted it.

So my suggestion is:  If the owner of a tumbleweed question comes back to the site when the tumbleweed is X days old (maybe a week, maybe a month, maybe somehow based on your percentages for the question ever being answered), ask the owner if he wants to just close it.  Odds are, he'll just close it then and there.

This won't fix questions by users who post a question and never come back, but it might fix questions by users like me without wasting moderator time.

Comment: But is that really what the site wants? If your question is good, isn't it better to retain it with the idea that there will eventually be an answer. Unless the technology involved becomes outdated and it's now irrelevant.

Comment: If you want to keep the post for posterity, perhaps a better solution would be to prompt the user to edit or close. Edits, per the original data, might lead to more attention (and perhaps a better-phrased question), and spurious questions that are of little worth could be closed.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/ really comes to mind. When the second person to have your exact same problem finds your question, he [feels less alone](https://xkcd.com/1576/). If a quarter of them get an answer at some point, as SuperBiasedMan, I'd rather let them stand.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the [Help & Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) queue is an alternative for the [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) queue if the Tumbleweeds should get inserted in an existing queue. There is a good chance that these Tumbleweeds don't need improvement, and it is already irritating to get H&I reviews of posts that were edited after Triage as it is often unclear those posts still need H&I.

Inserting the Tumbleweeds in Triage **might** be an idea, but the usefulness will be different for post that never were Triaged and those that already were. I am not sure whether all new posts now get into the Triage queue (or if there is some automated pre-selection/shifting). If a later Tumbleweed was originally Triaged for not needing improvement, it will probably not need Help & Improvement later on, nor a re-Triage. And this is even more unlikely  when Tumbleweeded post was not edited after its original Triage. If a later Tumbleweed  was Triaged to be not-OK in the first place, and was edited in the H&I queue, you might hope it doesn't benefit (much) from further improvement, and reinserting would unlikely result in improvements.

Inserting existing, not yet Triaged posts, from before the Triage queue's introduction (or ones that were not offered for Triage based on some automated shifting)  into the Triage queue might be an idea. But for the already Triaged ones, I would prefer your recommendation on a new queue.

Comment: +1 for "There is a good chance that these Tumbleweeds don't need improvement." I would have thought that questions are more likely to be ignored because they look hard or are outside almost all readers' expertise, rather than because they are bad questions. There's nothing wrong with SO having a lot of unanswered hard questions sitting around. The problem is that the chance encounters with those rare individuals who could answer them aren't happening.

Comment: I definitely agree, these don't need to go back in the queue if they've already been Triaged. A separate Tumbleweed queue would probably be better because reviewers there would know what they're looking at, and we could develop a list of common things to look for.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Spending some time on both Triage and H&I each day, this is what I focussed on answering. I think doing something about the Tumbleweeds in general is a good idea, just wanted to put in some weight keeping them out if H&I if not beneficial

Answer (score 5):

This problem is much bigger than meets the eye from the badge, there are also plenty of ignored and forgotten questions from SO users that already got the badge.  My perception is that it has been growing considerably in the past 1.5 years, one thing you can do with the data you have now is to plot it across time so we'll have some insight in how it has been evolving.

One thing I noticed is how stunningly ineffective close-voting has become.  The percentage of questions I voted on that actually end up getting closed is exceedingly low today.  I'd ballpark < 5% from looking at my profile history.  I did switch to downvoting questions much more heavily because of this, assuming the roomba gives much better odds for bad content to be removed.  I have no insight if that's actually accurate.

Voting to delete a post is an option I very rarely exercise.  The two-day wait is just too long.

Another problem I see is that questions that *should* get an answer just don't get one anymore.  Overwhelmed by questions that shouldn't.  That makes it a bit questionable to auto-delete the tumbleweeds, albeit that the odds that such a question attracts a late answer are very low.  I very rarely see that happen.

Content moderation has not been able to keep up with the rate it is getting added.  Been that way for the past 2 years.  Only true fix I see is to restrict access to the Ask Question button.  A very hard sell.

Comment: The number of Tumbleweed badges awarded is definitely growing every year. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vae73.png That's through the first 4.5 months of this year, so we're on pace to beat last year's mark. I agree that the sheer volume of questions we get is effecting how many we can answer. SO held solid at 80% answered for the first few years, and has slowly crept down to 74% in the last 2-3 years. Hopefully showing people more interesting and answerable questions on the front page will help turn that around.

Comment: Well, if that feature ever makes it then that's likely to generate a lot more tumbleweeds since everybody is looking at the good stuff :)  Graph is a bit of a surprise, I expected something a bit more exponential.  Might be because it is correlated to new users rather than weedy questions.

Answer (score 4):

From looking at these questions I believe there are two groups which cause the Tumbleweed badge to occur.

*Group #1: The optimists*

This group thinks that Stack Overflow is the end all, be all of knowledge and accidentally asks a question which is far too specific about some aspect of application design or implementation. It either involves a very specific aspect of a framework or tool, or a very specific aspect of implementing some design pattern.

The unfortunate part of this group of questions is that while these questions are not "too" broad, they are broad, and will require some time to properly answer in many cases either by showing a process for implementation or explaining a very nuanced but important aspect of design. Furthermore, these questions will need to be answered by someone with that specific type of expertise.

Eventually someone with enough expertise and time will find one of these questions and answer it. Apparently this take 6-8 months (okay, 9 as you state but I had to meta somewhere).

*Group #2: The telepaths*

This group thinks that Stack Overflow is a crowd source tool that reads minds  specifically built for their program. They include descriptions that no one can possibly understand but almost seem to make sense. Their questions are so off the wall that it is hard to tell if it needs an expert or needs a close vote, but since their title is also off the wall no one even goes there to check. [Invisible Designer in Visual Studio 2015 and 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444298/invisible-designer-in-visual-studio-2015-and-2013), for example. An invisible designer, for, you know, all those invisible things you need to create. Apparently this actually is an issue (I found a slight duplicate here: [Designer preview is invisible in Visual Studio 2013 and Blend 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353310/designer-preview-is-invisible-in-visual-studio-2013-and-blend-2013)) and you can see that there was a reference to an actual situation where the designer in Visual Studio was actually not showing any content. I don't know why and it would take someone with experience and knowledge (expertise?) with that tool to explain the why for that happening and the how for fixing it.

However, the question is barely legible. It only has 12 views, and 2 close votes. I am not sure, but statistically, having 16% of the viewers cast close votes is pretty bad. It would more than likely have been closed (rightfully) if it had more attention given to it.

Here is another one (5 views in a week) [How to change an image inside an Adobe Edge animation from externtal javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30442793/1026459) which is food for thought.

I think most of these questions really do break down into the two categories of mind readers versus nuanced.

*review queue to address this*

I am not sure that this problem can be solved by a review queue. The telepath group gets wiped out after a year by a script which seems far more efficient than burdening people with the task of dealing with these manually. The other group does seem to get answers at some point, but again that is how long it takes an actual expert in that topic to find the post *and* have time to answer it.

*this is more of a new user behavior*

I am more of the belief that the tumbleweed badge highlights a behavior of new users where they think Stack Overflow is a little too magical. I think this happens to many users when they first start asking questions (which is why you see the 1 in 20 ratio; 0.5M / 9.5M). This is also evidenced by looking at the average reputation of recent users "achieving" this badge. Of the first 360 surveyed, the average reputation was 36.

Addressing the approach new users take towards asking questions is something that is also being looked at right now. In fact, you can see a conversation about that right here: [Require new users to check the preview before posting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295683/1026459) . I believe that your review here of the tumbleweed badge just highlights the need to guide users through the question asking process at first so that they can become more aware of the both the required rigor and overall culture involved in asking questions here.

tldr; These questions seem to be from lower reputation users (average 36 from a medium sample). They are either too specific or unclear where the former eventually can be answered and the latter is probably removed. Helping new users ask questions is [something the team is going to be working on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295758/1026459).

Answer (score -2):

I think you're over-complicating this and just generating unnecessary work for the community. I take 2 simple things away from your analysis:

1. A tumbleweed has a 50% chance of getting an answer if it's edited more than 1.5 days after posting
2. 50% of these questions are getting automatically dealt with by the system, albeit a year later

The goal of Stack Exchange is to answer good questions, well and quickly. I don't see how adding tumbleweed's to a review queue will help achieve that as the OP will either have to be unbelievably lucky in who reviews their post (Help & Improvement/First Posts etc.) or the community will do a shed-load of work that the system will perform automatically (Close).

The simplest method of testing whether your analysis could have a meaningful impact would be to **have community bump the post *N* hours after it was posted**, if it's on track to become a tumbleweed. This would require A/B testing to determine the best timeframe, but it should be in a different timezone, i.e. 12, 36, 60 hours after posting. I suspect 12 would be too early...

It would be interesting to know how many of the original posters log back in (if you have the stats). An engaged user is more likely to interact with an answer and this could be used to prioritise those that get bumped if there are too many.

*If* there is a need to have the community close these questions, then we should **bring forward the automation deletion date by *N* days**. This would also require further analysis, but if, say, only 0.1% of questions get answered after 6 months the amount of harm caused in the system dealing with them at this time would be minimal.

Automatic deletion only really makes sense if we agree that these questions are not helping the internet. The contention seems to be that they've been forgotten and thus aren't. Fair enough, but we should be attempting to have someone remember them first.

Comment: As I said elsewhere, the point isn't to have a reviewer answer the questions, it's to get them to edit them so that someone else can. Some of these might just need a simple retag. Just bumping them doesn't do that. Also, you can see from the numbers I already showed that a full 10% are getting answered after 281 days (9 months). I don't think deleting them sooner without having people look at them is a good solution.

Comment: I will look at user activity, though. That's a good idea.

Comment: Guessing, I'd suspect that a bump puts a question in front of far more, more interested people, than a review queue @bill. Unless it's tagged incorrectly. If the latest edit was to add a top 50 tag then the additional answers make sense, otherwise it is just about getting the question in front of more people as you postulated.