# How can I get my non-trivial questions better received?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have anecdotally noticed a trend with the questions I ask on Stack Overflow.

Namely, the *easier* the question, the better received it is. This is something I've felt in a few ways with my questions seeing:

- Fewer votes
- Answers not actually answering the question at all
- I end up self-answering most of them

I am trying to figure out ways I can make these questions better received overall.

Many of the [questions I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048539/enderland?tab=questions) seem to fall into this category and end up answered only if I self-answer. Or if the questions are fairly trivial.

**Are there ways I can better write my more complicated questions such that they get better views?**

Note: I am explicitly asking how to make my questions better received, not complain

Comment: "Fewer votes" - I would see this as a good sign: There is still a  share of users that restrains itself from voting on something they don't completely understand instead of voting out of the blue.

Comment: @Murphy that's only a good sign if it's good for SO overall to encourage trivial questions vs more complex ones. Which I suppose is debatable.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295713/can-we-blow-away-some-of-the-tumbleweeds

Comment: I am explicitly asking how to make my questions better received, not lament the fall of the golden days. Rants are dime a dozen on MSO.

Comment: And another: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287163/why-are-so-many-useless-questions-ranked-highly-and-vice-versa

Comment: I see that part of my problem is people don't seem to read the actual question. Perhaps I don't make it clear what I'm asking? If I wanted to whine/complain, I would have done so. I am asking for, and I quote: `Are there ways I can better write my more complicated questions such that they get better views?` None of those links deal with that and are instead meta commentary/rants about the good ole days of SO, back when only good questions got asked, or something else.

Comment: @enderland I think that Murphy makes a good point. If someone doesn't fully understand the question or does not have/is not willing to take the time to understand it, they aren't going to vote on it. Then there's the issue that with more complicated questions, you need more advanced users to answer it. There's a whole lot more novice programmers in the world than there are experts. You could always try adding a TL;DR section at the top and/or adding a bounty.

Comment: @enderland Please select some of your "more complicated questions" and link them in your Meta question. People have different notions of what "complicated" means. There's no telling whether someone going through your questions is going to know what it is you had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is best answered by the many previous answers on the subject that I linked in the comments, so in this bigger box I'll tell you a story:

(Links from comments:)

- [Are we too preoccupied with easy questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297853/are-we-too-preoccupied-with-easy-questions)
- [Can we blow away some of the Tumbleweeds?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295713/can-we-blow-away-some-of-the-tumbleweeds)
- [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287163/why-are-so-many-useless-questions-ranked-highly-and-vice-versa)

---

My story:

I made a similar rant as you long ago here: [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/253066#253066)

In that MSO question, I posted links to two answers that I had posted that were:

1. Broadly useful to users of JavaFX / Swing and Google Gson, respectively
2. Required a lot of independent research and digging through source code
3. Had zero votes

Here they are:

- [how to stop "JavaFX Application Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808063/how-to-stop-javafx-application-thread/22997736#22997736)
- [How do I implement TypeAdapterFactory in Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307382/how-do-i-implement-typeadapterfactory-in-gson/22307855#22307855)

Both answers, today, now have 20+ upvotes each, **precisely because I linked them in a high traffic MSO thread**. They had zero velocity before I did so (feel free to check the timeline).

---

Bottom line: crowdsourcing what to upvote will result in the "best questions" being covered by [Parkinson's Law of Triviality (bikeshedding)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), and is compounded by [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

My only suggestion that has ever seemed to work (in my case, unintentionally) is to post the question somewhere else that isn't governed by FGITW, and perhaps has less traffic so it doesn't get instantly buried. I am **not advocating this approach**, but ultimately the problem you have identified is fundamental to the way voting works here and can't be fixed by simply writing a better question.

Comment: I am not trying to rant. I am trying to receive actionable, useful information about how to make my questions received. This answer is just a rant, apparently motivated by your bitter experiences with this in the past.

Comment: @enderland Fair, though I did provide actionable information. If you remove the ranty things from this answer you'll be left with "writing your questions better won't solve the problem" and "try posting links to your questions off-site", both of which are actionable advice.

Comment: So what you're saying is, enderland did everything precisely correct here. He posted a Meta question, with a link to his questions, so that he could sit back and reap the benefits of the Meta Effect?

Answer (score 1):

There's a relatively simple solution to this: Break your problem down into smaller problems that *are* trivial.

The reason trivial questions get received so well is because the audience for them is much larger. Like most things, debugging/problem solving in programming has a learning curve. You'll always have far more people on the lower end of the scale than the higher end. The bonus to my suggested solution is that you'll rather quickly get to a point where you no longer need to ask questions, thus putting you at the higher end of the scale.

Answer (score -7):

I experienced the same issue on Stack Overflow. I am using other Stack Exchange websites too and I can notice the issue is not the same everywhere. For example in [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) you have way more votes for questions about social issues than for technical ones about how works a point in the rules. As [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is very small compared to Stack Overflow the not-voted questions are still read by some people who actually read all the questions (or at list all the titles).

Considering that, a solution would be to open more small websites. Maybe separate the questions by languages (C, JavaScript, Python...) and keep a general central website.

I understand that it would be a huge mess to do such a change, but that's the only solution that comes to my mind.

Comment: The questions can already be easily separated by languages on Stack Overflow: just filter by the tag(s) you're interested in. Lots of people do this. Unfortunately, we still get so many C, Python, and JavaScript questions that even filtering to only one of those languages still means there are *way too many questions* to read all of them. There's no fix for this, other than reducing the question volume.

Comment: A tag system and a separation in two different websites is not the same thing. I am only getting conclusions from my observations: in more specialized websites this phenomenon is less a problem.

Comment: Because more specialized websites have a lot fewer questions total. If you created a Stack Overflow: Python, it would get just as many questions as Stack Overflow currently does with the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: @CodyGray and so what ? I don't get what you are trying to prove here.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Just that using more sites won't solve the problem, too much questions in a tag would be too much questions in a separate site as well. And that prevents cross tag questions (let's say php and js, Chef and ruby, R and python, aws-sdk and java for example, questions needing multiple tags to be defined would be duplicated on as many sites ?) => Won't Fix

Comment: I don't see how separating tags into sites would work, either. I'm active in 5 to 10 tags; if they were to be separated into 5 to 10 different sites, there's no way I would be following each. That's the case for most prolific answerers, I'm sure. To me, the problem described here is a simple question of how many questions there are, and how many developers willing and able to answer them

Comment: Just to stop the flood of comments: I never talked about separating tags into sites, but about creating more sites more specialized. It doesn't have to be separated along the tags.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Then why aren't you posting your own answer instead of saying that in comments ?

Comment: What sense would that make? You brought up the idea of separating the site, not the OP.

Comment: "To me, the problem described here is a simple question of how many questions there are, and how many developers willing and able to answer them" <- you seems to have a pretty strong opinion on the topic and your own idea about how to solve that.   Anyway people who ask specific difficult questions here don't need *you* to read them, they need someone who can actually answer. You may be very good at answering some specific answer but you can't be very good at answering *everything* here: the field covered by StackOverflow is just too big.

Comment: How would you propose things be separated? If a question involves 2-3 different programming languages, which site would it belong on?